# ASP.NET MVC 5 How to edit Parent and List<> type Child in same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, insert

I need to edit a class and its child of List type in the same view but I don't know how to make the child editing in the same view.

Let's say I have these classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int PValue1 { get; set; }
    public int PValue2 { get; set; }
    public int PValue3 { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ChildItem> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class ChildItem
{
    public int CValue1 { get; set; }
    public int CValue2 { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
@model MyNamespace.Parent

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveParent", "Index"))
{
    <label>Parent Value 1</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.PValue1, "", new { @class = "form-control" })

    <label>Parent Value 2</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.PValue2, "", new { @class = "form-control" })

    <label>Parent Value 3</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.PValue3, "", new { @class = "form-control" })

    @*  WHAT TODO? *@

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Child Value 1</th>
            <th>Child Value 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach(ChildItem item in Model.Childs){
            <tr>
            <td>@item.CValue1</td>
            <td>@item.CValue2</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

I need to make an insert code in the "WHAT TODO" area for the `Childs` child.
I tried using PartialView with something like:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyPartialView", Model.Childs)
```

And then in the PartialView create another form to use a `Insert(ChildItem child)` controller but I also couldn't achieve this. I didn't know how to make the second form add to the model because it was a List.

It's probably obvious right now, but I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and used to old WebForms, so still getting to understand somethings.

My goal is to accomplish a working view like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so with further study, I found out I dont need nested forms ou partial views, but multiple submit buttons with multiple form actions.
I got what I needed and apparently it was really basic, so I thought I could post my own solution to my own question and maybe help anybody else with same problem.
So, starting with the view I replaced this:

```
    @*  WHAT TODO? *@
```

With this:

```
    <label>Child Value 1</label>
    <input type="number" name="CValue1" />
    <label>Child Value 2</label>
    <input type="number" name="CValue1" />
    <!--This is the real trick! -->
    <input type="submit" formaction="AddChild" formmethod="post" />
```

The `formaction="AddChild"` fires the AddChild() action in the controller, submiting the Parent model and the `CValue1` and `CValue2` inputs.
But the `Childs` property of the model was always `null`,so, after executing the `AddChild` action, I was getting only the last added `ChildItem`.
To solve this, I had to make my controller recognize the `List<ChildItem>` in my `Parent` sending it separatelly in the post.
So, I had to change the list view from this:

```
@foreach(ChildItem item in Model.Childs){
   <tr>
     <td>@item.CValue1</td>
     <td>@item.CValue2</td>
   </tr>
}
```

To this:

```
 @for(int x = 0; x < Model.Childs.Count; x++){ 
  <tr>
     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Childs[x].CValue1)</td>
     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Childs[x].CValue2)</td>
     <td> <button type="submit" formaction="DeleteChild" name="ChildID" value="@Model.Childs[x].ID" formmethod="post">X</button>
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Childs[x].ID)
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Childs[x].CValue1)
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Childs[x].CValue2)
     </td>
  </tr>               
  }
```

The hidden fields store all the info for the controller binding.
Because of the index `x` for each line, when submiting the form, the controller can bind all child elements to the Child property correctly.

The controller for adding the Child:

```
public ActionResult AddChild(Parent parent, int CValue1, int CValue2){
  if (parent.Childs == null)
    parent.Childs = new List<ChildItem>();
  parent.Childs.Add(new ChildItem(){
    ID = parent.Childs.Count,  //This will be removed/improved later
    CValue1 = CValue1,
    CValue2 = CValue2
  });
  return View("Index", parent);
}
```

I also implemented the `DeleteChild` action:

```
public ActionResult DeleteChild(Parent parent, int ChildID){
   if (parent != null)
      parent.Childs.Remove(parent.Childs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == ChildID));
      return View("Index", parent);
}
```

It still missing all the database code, but thats the next step!